# Canvas text not showing? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, text

I am using the `ctx.fillText` function to draw text onto my screen and it doesn't seem to be appearing.

```
overlay("rgb(50, 50, 200)", "This is the beginning screen", 48, "black", "center", centerx, centery)

var overlay = function(colour, text, font, size, fontColour, oreintation, x, y){
    ctx.font = size + "px " + font + " " + fontColour
    ctx.textAlign = oreintation
    ctx.fillStyle = colour
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You must define your function `var overlay` before you call it with `overlay(...);
- centerx & centery are undefined
- the font face `font` is missing from `overlay(...)`
- the background fill is the same color as the text fill so the text does not show

Working demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var overlay = function(colour, text, font, size, fontColour, oreintation, x, y){
  ctx.font = size + "px " + font + " " + fontColour
  ctx.textAlign = oreintation
  ctx.fillStyle = colour
  ctx.fillStyle='gold';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
  ctx.fillStyle=fontColour,
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y)
}

overlay(
  "rgb(50, 50, 200)", 
  "This is the beginning screen",
  'verdana', 
  48, 
  "black", 
  "center", 
  25,
  50
);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```